# I'm trying to install VGA driver for s3 virge

Tags: drivers, video

and thank you in advance.  I have downloaded **xserver-xorg-video-s3virge_ 1.10.4 orig.tar.gz**, and extracted contents, which gives me  **xf86-video-s3virge-1.10.4**.  (Both files are sitting in my downloads folder).  When I run `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-s3virge`, I get the following message `E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-s3virge`.

- Where do I put **xserver-xorg-video-s3virge_1.10.4.orig.tar.gz** so
  `sudo apt-get install` can find it?
- Is there a program I need to enable Ubuntu to find and install this
  driver?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Hello, sir, thank you for your interest... I am running 14.04 Trusty Tahr.  I have rescued an IBM ThinkCentre A50 from the dumpster where I work and the onboard VGA had a problem with video. Video is very slow and stuttering, so I scrounged up an S3 video card which I have removed a couple of hours ago.  With the onboard VGA, video is also slow and stuttering.  When I had the pci card in, I could see BIOS  but when Ubuntu started, there was a black screen.  I could CTRL+ALT+DEL and get a menu to repair GRUB and then start normally, but there was still the slow stuttering video.

Comment: `apt-get` installs software from repositories. in your case it seems you are trying to install package from source or binary package.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get` doesn't work with tar.gz files, it downloads directly from so-called repositories from the internet.

To install, run `apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-s3virge`, the package is available in 10.04 and 12.04.

Comment: I think it's called `xserver-xorg-video-s3` only...

Comment: That may be part of the problem... I am running 14.04.

Comment: I ran 'apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-s3' and that gave me the message it was already the newest version.  Thanks everyone, it seems my driver is not my problem!  I'll try to figure out how to close this question.

Comment: what was your problem then @Pilgrim ?

Comment: @Pilgrim if you run into a problem you can't solve, better ask to this porblem from the beginning, instead of making up a new problem which won't solve the initial one. Please ask this in a new question.

Comment: Oh, hi guys!  The initial problem is on startup, I have no video.  I can ctrl+alt+del and go into advanced options for Ubuntu; I select Ubuntu + Linux and get a menu that allows me to repair the GRUB.  Then I start Ubuntu normally and have video, but it's very slow and the windows stutter when closed.

Comment: I'll do as the_Seppi suggests and detail the initial problem in a new question.  This is awesome, thanks for your time and help!